# How to add a checkbox for lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

so I am trying to add a checkbox for each contact in the list. This is what i have for now, but the checkboxes are not showing next to the contact names for some reason!

```
<div ng-controller="ContactsController" >
      <ons-list class="person-list" >
        <ons-list-header class="person-list-header" ng-init="people = contacts">{{char}}</ons-list-header>
          <ons-list-item class="person" modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="person in contacts | filter:searchInput">
            <ons-row>

              <ons-col class="checkbox checkbox--list-item">
                 <input type="checkbox">
                 <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark"></div>
              </ons-col>
              <ons-col class="person-name" ng-click="contactsBack(person.username)" >
                {{person.username}}
              </ons-col>
            </ons-row>
          </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
```

Comment: When you say "it's not working" what do you mean? What is it doing and how does that differ from what you expect it to be doing?

Comment: Checkboxes are not being added/displayed next to the contact names.what I'm expecting it to do is adding the selected contact to an array to create a group message. For now, i'm trying to get the checkboxes working so I can work on adding contacts to the array.

Comment: On the surface, apart from some weird stuff (not sure what you are using `ng-init` for nor what `{{char}}` is or where `searchInput` is defined) it looks like it should be working. Maybe you can create a JSFiddle or Plunker to illustrate the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lex mentioned - you have some code which is not relevant to the current problem - it's usually better if you don't put code which is irrelevant, but I guess it's not a problem in this case.

Basically since you're using the custom tags - all you need is `<ons-input type="checkbox"></ons-input>`.

Here's a [simple demo](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/BKwgEv?editors=1000).

Actually even the `ons-row` and `ons-col`s are not really needed unless you're doing something unusual - `ons-list-item` provides this functionality if you just add `left` and `center` classes to its children.

```
<ons-list-item class="person" modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="person in contacts">
    <ons-input type="checkbox" class="left" input-id="input-{{$index}}"></ons-input>
    <label class="center" for="input-{{$index}}">{{person.username}}</label>
</ons-list-item>
```